# Minimizing Product

Tags: algorithm, optimization, linear-programming

I am given 3 sets A, B and C, each with n elements. These sets can contain duplicates (not certain if Set is the right term).

Now I am trying to form a set D with n elements (say D1 to Dn), each element Di containing 3 elements, one from A, one from B and one from C.

My objective is to find the set D which minimizes the sum of products of elements in Di.

Brute force seems to be a pretty bad idea here because even for n>5, the algorithm slows down pretty badly. Can anyone suggest a better approach? Is Linear Programming suitable for this problem?

Comment: A set that contains duplicates is a [bag or multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)

Comment: Why does this question have three downvotes?! Unexplained, I might add? Impolite and ill-informed.

Comment: I am trying to find a counter-example, but so far the following approach seems to work: sort A, B and C, and iteratively match the largest element across all 3 arrays with the smallest of the 2 others. The intuition why this would work is that at each step, you minimize the "multiplying damage" of the largest remaining element. Would love a counter-example!

Comment: @Mathias: `{10, 11}, {1, 10}, {1, 10}`  Best is 220, your algorithm gives 1011.

Comment: Thanks Andrew - perfect example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to form two bipartite graphs that create a matching of elements of A-B and B-C, such that the average product (a_i * b_j * c_k) is minimized.

Unfortunately I believe this is an NP-hard problem.  (if you take the number of matchings n=3 as a variable)

I don't think the two matchings can be made seperately:

Consider A = {1, 10}, B = {1, 10}

The matching of A,B in isolation is 1 x 10 = 10 and 1 x 10 = 10 (for a total of 20)

However consider C = { 1, 10000 }

If we take the greedy match of A,B with C we get 10 x 1 = 10 and 10 x 10000 = 100000 (for a total of 100010)

However if we had of taken the non-optimal matching A,B as 1 x 1 = 1 and 10 x 10 = 100 (for a total of  101)

We could then match it with C as 1 x 10000 = 10000 and 100 x 10 = 1000 (for a total of 11000)

So we can see that it is necessary to consider all possible combinations.

This isn't a proof that it's NP-hard, but I hope it communicates an intuition.

Comment: The question is clearly tagged as "linear programming", which in its integer version is often used to optimize NP-Hard problems. Also: What is the suggested reduction?

Comment: If we translate it into log-space and add a row that has (small,large,large,...,large), I believe a solution could be used to solve TSP.  (but I'm not sure).  I am pretty sure this problem came up in my probabilistic graphical model class.

Comment: Whatever it is tagged, I think any exact solution has to be at least O(n^m) where the matching is m sets of n elements (here m = 3).

Comment: I am doubtful about the usefulness of linear programming here (but thinking about it): the objective is not linear in the arguments, and on top of that it's an integer programming problem (discrete variables).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching is NP complete, but the proof is for matchings where the scores for particular triples are abitrary, not three numbers multiplied together. Do you remember anything that covers this particular case? However, I can't think of any better approach that using repeated ordinary matchings/ assignment algorithm to try and hillclimb to a local optimum.

Comment: FWIW since we are minimising a sum of products we can minimise the 2-way matching by simply making one array in the opposite order from another (rewrite ab + cd - ad - cb as (a-c)(b-d)). But writing a program to hill-climb on these 2-way matchings finds multiple local optima for the same problem => no guarantee of finding global optimum, and on large problems seems entirely plausible that it misses them,